# B4A : ContentResolver error "Invalid token limit"

Tags: android, limit, android-contentresolver, android-11, vb4android

From Android 11, LIMIT and OFFSET should be retrieved using Bundle by

```
public Cursor query (Uri uri,String[] projection,Bundle queryArgs,CancellationSignal cancellationSignal)
```

I found it In bellow link :

[ContentResolver.query() method throws "Invalid token limit" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66280961/contentresolver-query-method-throws-invalid-token-limit-error)

How can I use limit with ContentResolver in B4A?

Comment: ContentResolver can do nothing for it. Its the uri provider/authority that handles your query(). ContentResolver is just the middle man. So tell which provider/authority you are querying.

Comment: from this "content://call_log/calls"